# the specs2 beRight matcher is not type-checked - is there an equivalent one that is?

Tags: specs2

Specs2 has these Either matchers:

```scala
private[specs2]
trait EitherBaseMatchers {

  def beRight[T](t: ValueCheck[T]) = RightCheckedMatcher(t)
  def beRight[T](implicit p: ImplicitParam = implicitParameter) = use(p)(new RightMatcher[T])

  def right[T : Diffable](t: T) = beRight(ValueChecks.valueIsTypedValueCheck(t))
  def right[T](t: ValueCheck[T]) = beRight(t)
  def right[T](implicit p: ImplicitParam = implicitParameter) = beRight(p)
```

So, `beRight` is not type-checked: how do I use the apparently type-checked ones (using Diffable I guess)?

P.S. of course I am aware of `must_===`, `beLike` and so on, that isn't the issue.

Comment: Can you try `beRight[MyType]` to specify what the type should be and avoid a unification to `Any`? Otherwise it seems that I need to revisit this API for the next major version because it's not very consistent

Comment: That works, in a sense, in that a type mismatch will produce an error message about "overloaded method with alternatives", however that isn't very intuitive. A type match does compile successfully. Definitely agree a consistent fully type-checked approach is very desirable.

Comment: Actually I can't find a better way to model this. In all cases the compiler will display the "overloaded method with alternatives". A way out is for you to define `def beRightAs[T] = beRight[T]` and then the error message will be more explicit. I'm reluctant for now to add this to the API since the current way works even if it is not the nicest.